# Page break on my page shows as simple horizontal line

Tags: pagination

I'm trying to divide a long tutorial I wrote into multiple pages. At the bottom of each page, viewers should see a "previous"/"next" button that takes them to the previous/next page (da!). I understood that this can be done by inserting "page breaks" however, when I do that, all I get are horizontal lines. Can anybody help me understand what I'm doing wrong? my page is located here : www.ez-26262.com, and if you look at the source, you can see the page breaks are inserted. The plug in is configured exactly as shown in step #2 in [this pagination tutorial](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/page-break-viral/). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do this is to group the articles into a category (if they aren't already), add the articles to the same menu and set "Show Navigation" = "Show" in the article or menu options (see below for an example).

The navigation order of the articles is controlled in Article Manager (filter to the specific category of articles and then sort in the required order).

[image: Show Navigation]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you give a bit more detail about your solution? I can't find a "Navigation" feature, only a "Show navigation" feature which is active by default, and it doesn't make all articles that belong to the same category have any next/previous buttons at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry, I answered this in a hurry without checking properly. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, but I don't think it is this answer's fault. The *show navigation* thing in Joomla seems to be one big mass, and can be defined in at least 3 different places.

Comment: It might also depend on the template you are using. Maybe try one of the default templates to see if it makes a difference.